# Es freut mich, Sie kennengelernt haben zu dürfen/Sie kennenlernen gedurft zu haben

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive

Welche der genannten Alternativen ist korrekt? Beim Googeln bin ich auf widersprüchliche Antworten auf diese Frage gestoßen.

> Es freut mich, Sie kennengelernt haben zu dürfen
>   Es freut mich, Sie kennenlernen gedurft zu haben

Comment: ein historischer Vergleich mit Englisch "have to" (ought to, etc.) und subjunktiv "Ich habe X zu Y-en" wäre hier angebracht.

Comment: Beide Alternativen sind ungebräuchlich fast bis zur Unverständlichkeit. Üblicher wäre "Es freut mich, dass ich Sie kennenlernen durfte".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der zu-Infinitiv des Infinitivsatzes ersetzt das finite Verb des gleichwertigen Objektsatzes. Da der Infinitiv keine Zeitform hat, ist die Zeit gleich der des Hauptsatzes.

> Es freut mich, Sie kennengelernt haben zu dürfen.

*Es freut mich, dass ich Sie kennengelernt haben darf.*

Diese Variante setzt das Dürfen in die Gegenwart und das Kennenlernen in die Vergangenheit. Das ist unlogisch.

---

> Es freut mich, Sie kennenlernen gedurft zu haben.

*Es freut mich, dass ich Sie habe kennenlernen dürfen.*

Ein finites *haben* steht solchen Infinitivreihen immer voran. Andere Hilfsverben können voranstehen, müssen aber nicht.

Diese Objektsatz-Variante setzt den gesamten Vorgang des Kennenlernen-Dürfens eindeutig in die Vergangenheit. Diese Variante ist daher auch die gebräuchliche. Die zugehörige Infinitivsatz-Variante ist zwar logisch richtig, aber ungebräuchlich.

Comment: Die Frage interessierte mich schon öfter, die Antwort hilft leider nicht. Satz 2 ist eine reine Behauptung, die ich zu bezweifeln wage (die ich bezweifeln zu wage???)

Comment: Da in Bsp. 2 das "es" den folgesatz bezeichnet, "es" in der Gegenwart ist, der Folgesatz aber in der Vergangenheit, ist jenes Bsp. immerhin *unlogisch*. Ist *dürfen* (relativ offensichtlich, viz *ü*, vgl *mag* / *mögen*) im Subjunktiv?

Comment: Auch ist *Darf ich Sie bitte kennengelernt haben?* für abwegige Lesungen der Verben nicht zwingend unlogisch, so etwa im Sinne der Antwort *Nein, dieses Treffen hat nie statt gefunden* (bzw. *Werde ich ...?*, *Nein, dieses Treffen wird nie ...*, aber da *nie* stativ ist, sollte das Verb es auch sein).

Comment: Ich glaube hingegen nicht, dass nach den vielen Bedeutungswandlungen des Verbs *dürfen* dessen althochdeutsche Eigenschaften noch irgendwo durchscheinen. Ich wüsste jedenfalls niemanden, der *dürfen* in einen natürlichen Zusammenhang mit der Vergangenheit bringt.

Comment: In *Darf ich Sie bitte kennengelernt haben?* ist die zeitliche Unlogik ein Stilmittel. Vergleiche: *Musste ich gestern schon gemacht haben.* gegen *Muss ich gestern schon gemacht haben.*

Comment: Es freut mich, eine so präzise Antwort lesen gedurft zu haben.

Answer (score 0):

[dürfen](https://dwds.de/wb/d%C3%BCrfen) "gehört zu den Präteritopräsentien", ist also formal bereits eine Vergangenheitsform, nämlich von *darben*.

Eine (wenn nicht *die*) korrekte Form lautet

> Es hat mich gefreut, Sie kennenlernen zu dürfen.

Darüber hinaus gilt "Er hat dürfen", nicht "er hat gedurft", landläufig als korrekt. Demnach sind weitere standardsprachliche Ableitungen sinnfrei.

"zu haben dürfen" gehört der Erfahrung nach nicht zum Repertoir. Es macht zwar wenig Sinn, *dürfen* in den Kontext zu setzen, wenn einfach *Sie kennen gelernt zu haben / gesehen zu haben* viel direkter ist.

Falls dennoch besonderer Wert darauf gelegt wird, wäre der feine Unterschied entscheidend, ob die Freude vor, während oder nach dem Kennenlernen bestand. Eine Zeitform die plusquamperfekt das (subjunktive?) Erlauben vor das ebenfalls vergangene Lernen setzt, wobei kennenlernen auch noch progressiv ist, existiert wahrscheinlich einfach nicht. Wird der feine Unterschied unterschlagen, dann wird der Subjunktiv / Konjunktiv einfach als fortwährend angenommen, denn die Erlaubnis kann nicht wirklich rückwirkend entzogen werden.

PS: Demnach wäre allenfalls Konjunktiv II (irrealis) kontrastierend, dann aber im Hauptsatz, während der Bedingungssatz im Konjunktiv I bleiben kann -- oder Präsenz; das ist aber eine andere Frage, die hier schon sicherlich mehrfach und zuletzt ohne Ergebnis diskutiert wurde; Es wäre schon, genaueres zu erfahren!